# Lens setter analogous to "monoidal" lens getter?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

In some cases, the `^.` lens **getter** defaults to `mempty` if the field being accessed is not present. Example:

```
let x = Nothing :: Maybe String

x ^. _Just == ""
```

What is the analogous lens **setter** with a similar behaviour? Here's what I'm looking for:

```
data MyRecord = MyRecord  { myrecordFoo :: Maybe Int  }
instance Monoid MyRecord where
  mempty = MyRecord { myRecordFee = Nothing }

$(makeLensesWith abbreviatedFields ''MyRecord)


let x = Nothing :: Maybe MyRecord

x & _Just . foo `someLensSetter` 10 == (Just $ MyRecord { myRecordFoo = 10 })
```

I've tried playing around with `<>~` and `<>=`, but couldn't get them to work in the way I expect above. Is this even possible? Is there some other standard combinator I should look at? Any custom combinator that can achieve this?

Comment: it seems to me like you want `(?~)` maybe?

Comment: Your description of what you're "looking for" is confusing.  `x` has two levels of `Maybe` -- are you trying to influence the outer, inner, or both?  Also, the `Monoid` instance for `MyRecord` is incomplete and seems irrelevant anyway if you want to use a `_Just.foo` optic to focus on the `Maybe Int` field.  It doesn't help that you're perhaps missing a `Just` in `myrecordFoo = 10`.  You might need to clarify what you're trying to do in order to get an answer.